Could not create instance of type: Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters
i'm working on the upgrade project from 8.2 to 10.4 and we are used custom provider for multiple scenario after the changes we are getting the below error.
Could not create instance of type: Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters:
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters:

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider. No matching constructor was found. Constructor parameters: ]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +574
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(List`1 nodes) +311
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider) +323
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders() +75
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider() +116
   Sitecore.Data.DefaultStandardValuesManager..ctor(ProviderHelper`2 providerHelper) +18
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +407
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +274
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +158
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +377
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) +63
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +279
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) +103
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider) +51
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.LazyResetable`1.get_Value() +150
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetStandardValue() +21
   Sitecore.Pipelines.GetFieldValue.GetStandardValue.Process(GetFieldValueArgs args) +34
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +294
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue, Boolean allowInheritValue, Boolean allowInnerValue) +333
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue, Boolean allowInheritValue) +44
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.GetValue(Boolean allowStandardValue, Boolean allowDefaultValue, Boolean allowFallbackValue) +29
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field.get_Value() +25
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccessRules(Item item) +59
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.GetAccessRules(ISecurable entity) +18
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemSecurity.GetAccessRules() +48
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType) +313
   Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType) +50
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +331
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +195
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight) +106
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.DefaultAuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable entity, AccessRight right, Account account) +105
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess.CanRead() +63
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +81
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +147
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +154
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper) +874
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, IItemRepositoriesSettings settings, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper) +234
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +407
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +274
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) +158
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) +377
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) +63
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +279
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +75
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) +103
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider) +51
   Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor..ctor() +31
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) +560
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) +365
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +481

[ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor, Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +138
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +136
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1437
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +918
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeOutcomeDefinitionRepositoryProcessor, Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Marketing.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719

and please find the configuration file
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="switcher" />
      <providers>
        <add name="switcher" fallback="sitecore" type="Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider, Project.ww.Common" />
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

and respective file
  public class SwitchingStandardValuesProvider : StandardValuesProvider
  {
      private const string FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = "fallback";

      public SwitchingStandardValuesProvider(BaseItemManager itemManager, BaseTemplateManager templateManager, BaseFactory factory) : base(itemManager, templateManager, factory)
      {
      }

      private string Fallback { get; set; }

      public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
      {
          base.Initialize(name, config);
          Fallback = config[FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTE_KEY];
          Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(Fallback, "fallback");
      }

      public override string GetStandardValue(Field field)
      {
          string providerName = Fallback;

          LazyResetable<ProviderHelper<StandardValuesProvider, StandardValuesProviderCollection>> providerHelper = ServiceLocator.GetRequiredResetableService<ProviderHelper<StandardValuesProvider, StandardValuesProviderCollection>>();
          var providers = providerHelper.Value.Providers;
          StandardValuesProvider standardValuesProvider = null;
          if (providers == null && providers.Count > 0)
          {
                  foreach (StandardValuesProvider svProvider in providers)
                  {
                      var iProvider = svProvider as ISwitchingStandardValuesProvider;
                      if (iProvider != null)
                      {
                          if (!iProvider.FieldMappings.ContainsKey(field.ID))
                              continue;

                          standardValuesProvider = svProvider;
                          providerName = svProvider.Name;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
              
              //find the provider
              //standardValuesProvider = standardValuesProvider ?? StandardValuesManager.Providers[Fallback];

          //return the GetStandardValue call
          return standardValuesProvider?.GetStandardValue(field);
      }
  }


In Sitecore, when you are configuring providers in the web.config (or any similar patch configuration file), the resolve="true" attribute instructs Sitecore's factory system to use dependency injection (DI) to resolve and instantiate the provider.
Here's how your updated configuration should look with the resolve="true" attribute:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="switcher" />
      <providers>
        <!-- Ensure the provider is resolved via DI -->
        <add name="switcher" fallback="sitecore" type="Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider, Project.ww.Common" resolve="true" />
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this help!!

hi @praveen, Thanks for the answer that is working, after that got another error "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.ww.Common.Providers.wwCategoryStandardValuesProvider'." it is reltated to dependency injection

Hi @Ramesh I have updated my answer pls check

You will need to add resolve as true where you are patching the standard value provider as below.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <standardValues>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider" value="switcher" />
      <providers>
        <add name="switcher" fallback="sitecore" type="Project.Common.Providers.SwitchingStandardValuesProvider, Project.ww.Common" resolve="true"/>
      </providers>
    </standardValues>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case face any issues.

hi, Thanks for the answer that is working, after that got another error "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.ww.Common.Providers.wwCategoryStandardValuesProvider'." it is reltated to dependency injection

@Rameshkumar Can you please share stack trace for this error in the above answer.

You can also check in wwCategoryStandardValuesProvider configuration, resolve=true is added. This is required to resolve the dependency of the constructor parameters in this class..

Updated the question. wwCategoryStandardValuesProvider configuration, resolve=true that is added.

@Rameshkumar This class CategoryStandardValuesProvider seeme to be be a different one that added on above answer. Can you share the config patch from where this class CategoryStandardValuesProvider has been injected.

i will create a seperate question
